# How many different ways are there to use Hit Dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-dice

I'm trying to create the ultimate *Bloodwell Vial* build for D&D 5e. But I have hit a small snag...

For those who don't know, the [*Bloodwell Vial*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/2412091-bloodwell-vial) is a magic item that lets you regain 5 sorcery points when you use Hit Dice to recover HP (useful for sorcerers and anyone with the Metamagic feat).

How many different ways are there to use Hit Dice? I know about:

- resting,
- healing surge action, and
- the Dwarven Resilience feat

But are there more?

Comment: Before you go too deep into making a build, this feature of the *bloodwell vial* can only be used once. I suspect you'll find short rest hit dice are sufficient to leverage that feature.

Comment: What you, David Coffron, said is wrong, it's not one and done, it's once/dawn; which means little to a divine soul sorcerer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Leopomon. Is there something about a Divine Soul that lets you ignore daily use limits on items? You can still only use it once per day, so having many ways to expend a hit die would give you slightly more flexibility but wouldn't let you pull dozens of sorcery points per day.

Comment: If this is what you mean, you will need a very lenient DM to use the *dawn* spell to refresh magic item. I interpret the recharge at dawn qualities to refer to the time of dawn, rather than just the light of dawn.

Comment: @DavidCoffron It's simple to test this hypothesis: does the item recharge indoors/underground? If it does, it wasn't the light of dawn that mattered after all.

Answer (score 7):

### These are the ways you can spend hit dice to heal in 5e:

- During a **short rest**. (Note: The spell *catnap* alows for a 10 minute short rest once per day)
- The **Dwarven Fortitude** feat allows you to spend a hit dice when you take the dodge action.
- The optional **Healing Surges** rule in the DMG allows you to take an action to spend a hit die to heal.
- The spell ***Wither and Bloom*** from Strixhaven allows one creature to heal itself using one of its own hit dice.
- An **autognome** from the Astral Adventurer's Guide can spend a hit-die when mending is cast on it.

Comment: It might be valuable to mention the *catnap* spell which allows for a 10 minute short rest once per day

Comment: On roughly the same level of availability as *Dwarven Fortitude*, the Spelljammer Autognome can spend a hit die to roll it and heal that much +Con mod each time *Mending* is cast on them.

Comment: I should point, ShadowRanger, that the feat was originally called Dwarven resilience in Unearthed Arcana.